# Multiple Selection Listview Function in UWP

Tags: c#, json, listview, uwp

I have an "updateList" listview with multiple selection. I want if the user clicks (selects / checked) the item in the listview, it will go to "selectedUpdateList" listview. And if the user clicks (unchecked) the same item on the listview, then the item will be deleted from "selectedUpdateList" listview.
XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="updateList" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,10,20,20"
                          AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
                          AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                          IsSwipeEnabled="False" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True" IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="True" ItemClick="UpdateList_ItemClick">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{x:Null}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <!--<CheckBox Grid.Column="0" />-->
                                <Image Grid.Column="1" Height="110" Width="168" Source="images/folder2.png" />

                                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding ID}" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black" FontSize="17" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="95" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="10,5,0,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding Judul}" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black" FontSize="17" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListView>

                <ListView x:Name="selectedUpdateList" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,10,20,20"
                          AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
                          AutomationProperties.Name="Items" Visibility="Collapsed"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                          IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{x:Null}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Height="110" Width="168" Source="images/folder2.png" />

                                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding ID}" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black" FontSize="17" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,5,0,0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Background="{x:Null}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,10" Text="{Binding Judul}" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black" FontSize="17" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListView>
```

Code:

```
try
{
    string urlPath = "http:/..../index.php/fetchupdate";
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {

    };

    string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JsonArray jsonArray = JsonArray.Parse(jsonText);
    foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
    {
        JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
        string idfile = groupObject["idfile"].GetString();
        string judul = groupObject["judul"].GetString();

        UpdateData update = new UpdateData();
        update.ID = idfile;
        update.Judul = judul;
        DataUpate.Add(update);
    }
    updateList.ItemsSource = DataUpate;
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
    requestErrorStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
private void UpdateList_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickedItem is UpdateData selectedItem)
    {
        selectedItem.IsSelected = !selectedItem.IsSelected;
        if (selectedItem.IsSelected == true)
        {
            UpdateData selected = new UpdateData();
            selected.Judul = selectedItem.Judul;
            selected.ID = selectedItem.ID;
            selectedData.Add(selected);
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateData selected = new UpdateData();
            selected.Judul = selectedItem.Judul;
            selected.ID = selectedItem.ID;
            selectedUpdateList.Items.Remove(selected);
        }
    }
    selectedUpdateList.ItemsSource = selectedData;
}
```

If you use the code above when you click on an item (unchecked) in the "updateList" listview, the item is not deleted from "selectedUpdateList" listview. How to handle it?

Comment: If I did not misunderstand your question, you need to delete the item from `selectedData` instead of `selectedUpdateList.Items`.

Comment: I want to delete the item from "selectedUpdateList" listview on the item unchecked in the "updateList" listview

Comment: If the item still is existed in `selectedData`, there's no effect. Because you specify the `selectedUpdateList.ItemsSource = selectedData`.

Comment: how to fix the problem?

Comment: As I said, you need to remove the item from selectedData.

Comment: I have replaced it to selectedData.Remove (itemDetail); but the item still isn't deleted on "selectedUpdateList" listview

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I want if the user clicks (selects / checked) the item in the listview, it will go to "selectedUpdateList" listview. And if the user clicks (unchecked) the same item on the listview, then the item will be deleted from "selectedUpdateList" listview.

Since you do not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I just made a simple code sample to achieve the same effect according to your requirement.

Please check the following code sample:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView x:Name="updateList" ItemsSource="{Binding updateDatas}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,10,20,20"
                      AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
                      AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      IsSwipeEnabled="False" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True" IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="UpdateList_SelectionChanged">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{x:Null}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Height="110" Width="168" Source="images/folder2.png" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding ID}" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black" FontSize="17" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="95" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="10,5,0,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding Judul}" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black" FontSize="17" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>

    <ListView x:Name="selectedUpdateList" ItemsSource="{Binding selectedData}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,10,20,20"
                      AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
                      AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{x:Null}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Height="110" Width="168" Source="images/folder2.png" />

                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding ID}" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black" FontSize="17" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,5,0,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Background="{x:Null}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,10" Text="{Binding Judul}" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black" FontSize="17" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<UpdateData> updateDatas { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<UpdateData> selectedData { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        updateDatas = new ObservableCollection<UpdateData>();
        selectedData = new ObservableCollection<UpdateData>();
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            updateDatas.Add(new UpdateData() {ID=i,Judul="Judul "+i });
        }
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void UpdateList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
        {
            selectedData.Add((UpdateData)item);
        }
        foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
        {
            selectedData.Remove((UpdateData)item);
        }
    }
}

public class UpdateData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Judul { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for delayed respond. And how to display it in listview? Because I try selectedUpdateList.ItemSource = selectedData cannot appear in selectedUpdateList listview

Comment: @Rose You could try to create a new blank UWP project and copy my code to test. I believe that you could understand what l’m doing.